# synchronization issue with 3 threads and 2 shared resources in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, deadlock

i have 3 thread and 2 shared resources, which need some locking...i tried to illustrate the resources with 2 buffers...
- thread 1 can only access resource 1
- thread 2 can access resource 1 and 2
- thread 3 can access resource 1 and 2

can someone tell me why the following locking fails? since thread2 and thread3 will access resource 1 and 2...i thought i could use try_lock? ...it seems the issue pops up, when thread2 and thread3 is only able to lock 1 mutex at a time...any idea?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 
#include <mutex> 
#include <condition_variable> 
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 
#include <cassert> 
using namespace std; 

class SynchronizationTest { 
private: 
    mutex lock_r1; 
    mutex lock_r2; 
    vector<pair<string, int>> buffer_r1; 
    vector<pair<string, int>> buffer_r2; 
    unsigned int buffer_r1_max_size; 
    unsigned int buffer_r2_max_size; 

    bool buffer_r1_inc_element(const string &thread_id) {       
        if (buffer_r1.size() == buffer_r1_max_size) { 
            return true; 
        } 

        if (buffer_r1.size() == 0) { 
            buffer_r1.push_back(make_pair(thread_id, 0)); 
        } 
        else { 
            int last_val = buffer_r1.back().second; 
            buffer_r1.push_back(make_pair(thread_id, ++last_val)); 
        } 

        return false; 
    } 

    bool buffer_r2_inc_element(const string &thread_id) {   
        if (buffer_r2.size() == buffer_r2_max_size) { 
            return true; 
        } 

        if (buffer_r2.size() == 0) { 
            buffer_r2.push_back(make_pair(thread_id, 0)); 
        } 
        else { 
            int last_val = buffer_r2.back().second; 
            buffer_r2.push_back(make_pair(thread_id, ++last_val)); 
        } 

        return false; 
    } 

public: 
    SynchronizationTest(int buff_r1_size, int buff_r2_size) : buffer_r1_max_size(buff_r1_size), 
                                                              buffer_r2_max_size(buff_r2_size) {} 

    void thread1() { 
        bool buffer_r1_full = false; 

        while (!buffer_r1_full) { 
            { 
                unique_lock<mutex> l(lock_r1, std::defer_lock); 
                if (l.try_lock()) { 
                    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread1"); 
                } 
            } 

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10)); 
        } 
    } 

    void thread2() { 
        bool buffer_r1_full = false; 
        bool buffer_r2_full = false; 

        while (!buffer_r1_full || !buffer_r2_full) { 
            { 
                unique_lock<mutex> lock1(lock_r1, defer_lock); 
                unique_lock<mutex> lock2(lock_r2, defer_lock); 

                int result = try_lock(lock1, lock2); 
                if(result == -1) { 
                    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread2"); 
                    buffer_r2_full = buffer_r2_inc_element("thread2"); 
                } 
                else if(result != 0) { 
                    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread2"); 
                } 
                else if(result != 1) { 
                    buffer_r2_full = buffer_r2_inc_element("thread2"); 
                } 
            } 

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10)); 
        } 
    } 

    void thread3() { 
        bool buffer_r1_full = false; 
        bool buffer_r2_full = false; 

        while (!buffer_r1_full || !buffer_r2_full) { 
            { 
                unique_lock<mutex> lock1(lock_r1, defer_lock); 
                unique_lock<mutex> lock2(lock_r2, defer_lock); 

                int result = try_lock(lock1, lock2); 
                if(result == -1) { 
                    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread3"); 
                    buffer_r2_full = buffer_r2_inc_element("thread3"); 
                } 
                else if(result != 0) { 
                    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread3"); 
                } 
                else if(result != 1) { 
                    buffer_r2_full = buffer_r2_inc_element("thread3"); 
                } 
            } 

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10)); 
        } 
    } 

    void print_buffer() { 
        for_each(buffer_r1.begin(), buffer_r1.end(), [](pair<string, int> p) { cout << p.first.c_str() << " " << p.second << endl; }); 
        cout << '\n'; 
        for_each(buffer_r2.begin(), buffer_r2.end(), [](pair<string, int> p) { cout << p.first.c_str() << " " << p.second << endl; }); 
    } 
}; 

int main() { 
    // your code goes here 
    SynchronizationTest st(20, 20); 

    thread t1(&SynchronizationTest::thread1, &st); 
    thread t2(&SynchronizationTest::thread2, &st); 
    thread t3(&SynchronizationTest::thread3, &st); 

    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
    t3.join(); 

    st.print_buffer(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::try_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/try_lock) does not work that way. If it returns -1, all locks are held. If it returns a non-negative integer, **no locks are held**. The returned value tells which lock failed, but any locks that were locked successfully are released before `try_lock` returns.

Comment: how do you know which lock was successfully if the return is not -1? -1 says both locks can be aquired...?

Comment: @Gerald `try_lock` (like `lock`) attempts to acquire *all* the locks you pass to it in a deadlock-free manner. If `try_lock` returns -1, it locked them all. If it returns a non-negative integer `N`, it acquired the first `N` arguments before failing to `try_lock` the `N`th argument and then released the first `N` arguments before returning. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock1(lock_r1, defer_lock);
unique_lock<mutex> lock2(lock_r2, defer_lock);

bool result1 = lock1.try_lock();
bool result2 = lock2.try_lock();

if(result1 && result2) {
    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread2");
    buffer_r2_full = buffer_r2_inc_element("thread2");
}
else if(result1) { 
    buffer_r1_full = buffer_r1_inc_element("thread2");
}
else if(result2) { 
    buffer_r2_full = buffer_r2_inc_element("thread2");
}
```